# Selection goes through objects

Tags: modeling, objects, selection-tools

I am working on a kind of Voxel design. However, whenever i use box or circle select in object mode, it selects all of the objects in the path, not just the visible ones, how can i get around this so i only select the ones on the surface?

Comment: probably may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/selection-behavior-and-limit-selection-to-visible?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior, At the moment circle selection in object mode uses object centers only.

Comment: I wish it made that clear in the Blender docs.