# Why can see through my object in solid?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode

[image: lamp in blender]
[image: top view of lamp in blender]

This is how it looks when I am in solid view. It is very annoying to edit like this - how can I make it look normal?

Comment: This should solve your problem: [Selection Behavior and Limit Selection to Visible](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3328/2217)

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/edit-mode-transparent-objects

Answer (score 1):

you have unchecked limit selection to visible. To undo that, just click it again.[image]