# How to turn off partial wireframe?

Tags: modeling

I have this going on:

[image]

This "partial wireframe" thing is really annoying and I have no idea how I enabled it and I need to disable it.

Comment: Is this in Edit Mode or Object Mode? In case Edit Mode, are you using a Mirror Modifier?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/edit-mode-transparent-objects and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/selection-behavior-and-limit-selection-to-visible

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by partial? Is it bothering you that you see the mesh that is behind objects? Is it bothering you that you don't see the mirror of the mesh wireframe? Is there something else that you are concerned with?

Comment: I managed to fix it. It was caused by some button on the toolbar that had two boxes on it... Can't describe it much more :(