# Split a Mesh with a curve (knife project tool)

Tags: mesh, knife-tool, bisect

I'm developing an add-on in Blender and I need to manipulate in Blender before developing the tool.

My goal : I want to split a mesh in two different meshes with the Knife Project tool in Blender. I already see many forum talking about that and I already tried all the different solution mentioned. The best one for my issue is this one : [Separate in two parts a mesh with knife project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67866/separate-in-two-parts-a-mesh-using-knife-project?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My issue : When I try the method from the link above (with knife project and not with bisect tool), when I project to cut, the cutting edge is not the only thing selected.  I have many faces selected too and I don't want this. I only want the cutting edge to be selected to continue the process to separate each part of the mesh. Of course with manipulation we can just unselect the faces but it's not a possible way to do this by scripting.

It works perfectly with Bisect tool, but I don't always cut a simple line, I often have to cut with bezier curves so Knife Project tool should be the best way I think ?

Is there a way simply select the cutting edge after cutting with the Knife Project tool or is there a completely other way to split a mesh in two different part ?

[image]

Thanks!