# Cut object into two objects with a plane

Tags: modifiers, objects

is there a way to cut an object into two objects with a plane without duplicate that object and extruding the plane in both direction applying a boolean operation?

My mesh is complicated because it is generated by a 3d scanning so the knife project isn't enought.

The knife project gives me the line where the two object should be separated, but i need to separate the objects manually along a very complicated mesh resulting in a waste of time.

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/cutting-a-mesh-in-half https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50591/how-to-select-part-of-a-mesh-by-using-a-helper-plane

Comment: Xylvier, thank you very much for writing this add-on.
It is exactly what I need for a project I am working on.
With limited experience in mesh manipulation I need to show results to my employer, and your add-on is helping me get there, while creating time for me to learn to work properly with meshes from scratch.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

While i can suggest to use bisect, i have an even better solution, i wrote a little "free" add-on for exactly this situation. Called it Bisectplus, as it can take a plane object and generate 3 vertex groups which represent the cut loop, as well as both sides (which include the center each) to make it easy to use for further operations.

The source-code can be found under https://github.com/Xylvier/Bisectplus/

As it says, seeing is believing:
[image: Suzanne standing in for a bisection demonstration]
No harm was done to the monkey.

Answer (score 0):

even if you cut objects with a plane, you will not able to see it, because plane has thickness of 0. you make create loop, and cut it with a V button