# How to drag select through all geometries, not just visible geometry

Tags: selection-tools

(Using Blender 2.90)
I have a model that has lots of extra geometry (polygons) that I want to delete. I know that I can drag select geometry and then use `Ctrl+X` to "Dissolve Vertices". My question is, how do I drag select such that I can select all of the hidden faces/vertices as well as the visible geometry so that when I delete, any and all geometry that fit inside that drag-selected box goes away?

In essence, the problem I am trying to solve is that I have to drag and select the exact same box multiple times to actually delete all of the geometry, and that is a waste of time as well as prone to errors in mouse movement.

How do I drag-select and include all visible and non-visible geometry?
Better yet, is there a toggle to switch between visible geometry only and both visible and non-visible when using drag-select?

I see this answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/selection-behavior-and-limit-selection-to-visible) that looks like what I want, but it references a version of blender that does not match what I have, and I am a noob at Blender, so I do not know how to translate that question into something I can operate on.

Comment: If I udnerstand the question, switch viewport shading to Wireframe (Z shortcut in default keymap for pie menu). The direct analogue of option mentioned in the linked answer as of 2.8+ is to enable X-Ray in the top right of default viewport (which in Wireframe mode is on, but you can use X-Ray in any mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way in current versions.
Just toggle the *X-Ray* button and you can select all faces/vertices under the cursor.

[image]